# How to match all substrings by words?

Tags: elasticsearch

Index: `["sell", "everything", "and", "live", "in", "live in", "sell car", "and me"]`

Input: `"sell everything and live in"`

Output(should be found): `["sell", "everything", "and", "live", "in", "live in"]`

How to solve now:

```
  query: {
    match: {
      text: {
        query: "sell everything and live in"
      }
    }
  }
```

-> `["sell", "everything", "and", "live", "in", "live in", "sell car", "and me"]` and manually select substrings.

In other words, I need tokenizer: 

`"So do I" -> ["so", "do", "i", "so do i", "so do", "do i"]`

Comment: Have a look at the shingles token filter https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html

Comment: @falomir Yes, I tried it, but how to build query, which discard matches like "sell car", "and me" etc.